# sed Remove lines ending in [0-9]%

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed

I'm writing a script that logs stdout-stderr.

The log contains multiple instances of:

```
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 52099 files and directories currently installed.)
```

How can I remove lines ending in `[0-9]%` - so the lines become:

```
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 52099 files and directories currently installed.)
```

---

I've tried various forms of:

`sed -i '/[0-9%]$/d' ~/test/Log`

...including escaping % - but no luck. I couldn't get any of the examples I found to work.

I'm specifically wanting to use `sed`, any ideas?

---

The `sed -i '/[0-9%]$/d' ~/test/Log` line appears to work on a test file - but not on the actual log for some reason.

I have tried `/%$/d` (probably works on a test file) - it didn't work on the log..

I tried `/[0-9]%$/d` - but no effect on the log file...

---

`sed` version:

```
~ sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2
```

Path to log `~/test/Log`

---

`'/[0-9]%[[:blank:]]*$/d'` doesn't appear to change the log either..

With regard to output - there is no error. Cat'ing the file shows correct output (lines removed)...

---

Note:

I'm discovering when I `cat` the file the lines are gone - when I open the file in my editor (Sublime Text 3) - the lines still show.

I tried rebooting in case there was a swap file somewhere but I'm still getting the same results.

Comment: Your line works for me: Gnu sed 4.2.2

Comment: Talking about what you've posted, have you tried with `/%$/d` expression?

Comment: Edited question to answer comments..

Comment: Can you share also the output when executing the line please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the file had control characters - specifically: ^M

**`cat` did not show the ^M -- but `less` did..**

The `less` output looks like:

```
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates/main policykit-1 amd64 0.105-8ubuntu3 [51.6 kB]
Fetched 102 kB in 0s (144 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package libpolkit-agent-1-0:amd64.
(Reading database ... ^M(Reading database ... 5%^M(Reading database ... 10%^M(Reading database ... 15%^M(Reading database ... 20%^M(Reading database ... 25%^M(Reading database ... 30%^M(Reading database ... 35%^M(Reading database ... 40%^M(Reading database ... 45%^M(Reading database ... 50%^M(Reading database ... 55%^M(Reading database ... 60%^M(Reading database ... 65%^M(Reading database ... 70%^M(Reading database ... 75%^M(Reading database ... 80%^M(Reading database ... 85%^M(Reading database ... 90%^M(Reading database ... 95%^M(Reading database ... 100%^M(Reading database ... 52099 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libpolkit-agent-1-0_0.105-8ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpolkit-agent-1-0:amd64 (0.105-8ubuntu3) ...
```

Note the "(Reading database" line is one long string (with ^M).

Removing the line with `sed` removes the whole line, now it's obvious why.

`sed` string replace acknowledges parts of the string, so it can be used to break down the line.

This is what wound up working (^M is \r on string):

```
sed -i 's/(Reading database \.\.\. [0-9]%\r//g' ~/Desktop/Log
sed -i 's/(Reading database \.\.\. [0-9][0-9]%\r//g' ~/Desktop/Log
sed -i 's/(Reading database \.\.\. [0-9][0-9][0-9]%\r//g' ~/Desktop/Log
sed -i 's/(Reading database \.\.\. \r//g' ~/Desktop/Log
sed -i '/^\s*$/d' ~/Desktop/Log
```

That replaces the specified part of the line with 'nothing', the last line removes lines with 'nothing'... so the result is:

```
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates/main policykit-1 amd64 0.105-8ubuntu3 [51.6 kB]
Fetched 102 kB in 0s (144 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package libpolkit-agent-1-0:amd64.
(Reading database ... 52099 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libpolkit-agent-1-0_0.105-8ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpolkit-agent-1-0:amd64 (0.105-8ubuntu3) ...
```

I'm positive there's an easier way - but none of my experiments worked including grouping (`{[0-9],[0-9][0-9],[0-9][0-9][0-9]}`), etc...

After hours of messing with it, I'm willing to accept my long-winded answer.. :)

---

**Update**

User *don_crissti* has a more efficient solution that achieves the same result:

`sed 's/.*(Reading/(Reading/'`

(...waiting to accept if he posts)

Comment: Right - If I was a sed expert I wouldn't of posted a question... Can you post what would work and be better? (the double line is a typeo - i'll edit that out..)

Comment: @don_crissti - That does work!! (`sed 's/.*(Reading/(Reading/'`)... If you post it as an answer noting all on one line, I'll accept it!

Comment: gotcha - I was wondering, makes sense!

Comment: Aside: did you know about cat -e? It prints control characters as well.

Answer (score 3):

You should not have the `%` within the brackets. The correct implementation is:
`sed -i '/[0-9]%$/d' ~/test/Log`

Comment: Maybe make it "sed -ri '/[0-9]%$/d' ~/test/Log" to try extended regular expressions? This regex worked for me as well.

Comment: Yeah, I was grasping for straws. sed -ri '/^.*[0-9]+%/ d' ~/test.log works for me as well.

Comment: No need for `^.*`, that just makes it run slower. You are looking for a match in the string, it's redundant to state that around the found pattern, there's other arbitrary stuff. You do need `$` in case the percentages appear also in the middle of lines, and you want to keep them.

Comment: @orion - you wouldn't happen to be the orion that used to work for a hosting company?

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for `grep`:

```
grep -vE '[0-9]%$'
```

the v means in**v**ert, and E is **E**xtended regexp.

Comment: Although this works, the user has stated that he specifically wants `sed` to be used. "I'm specifically wanting to use sed, any ideas?"

Comment: And nothing in that pattern requires `-E`.

Answer (score 0):

Your log file probably has spaces or tabs or other non-printing characters at the end, after the '%'.  Try:

```
 grep "Reading Database" ~/Test/Log | cat -A
```

(NOTE: `cat -A` requires GNU cat, which I assume you have because you have GNU sed)

If there's anything at all between `%` and `$` on those lines, then that confirms it.  In that case, change your sed script to:

```
sed -i '/Reading Database.*[0-9]+%/d'
```